# cassandra bulk loader database descriptor null pointer exception

Tags: cassandra

I'm new to cassandra and trying to follow the bulk load example on the following blog:

http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/using-the-cassandra-bulk-loader-updated

If I use the packaged jar that's provided and run the example it works.

If I, instead, try to use the provided source file (https://github.com/yukim/cassandra-bulkload-example/blob/master/src/main/java/bulkload/BulkLoad.java) and run the resulting jar I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at org.apache.cassandra.cql3.statements.UpdateStatement.addUpdateForKey(UpdateStatement.java:109)
at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.CQLSSTableWriter.rawAddRow(CQLSSTableWriter.java:218)
at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.CQLSSTableWriter.addRow(CQLSSTableWriter.java:138)
at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.CQLSSTableWriter.addRow(CQLSSTableWriter.java:113)
at bulkload.BulkLoad.main(BulkLoad.java:145)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.createAllDirectories(DatabaseDescriptor.java:605)
at org.apache.cassandra.db.Keyspace.<clinit>(Keyspace.java:73)
... 5 more
```

I haven't changed anything in the file from the example. I assumed it would have the exact same result as running the jar file that is provided in the same example, but it didn't. Can someone explain what I did wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Also, would it be inadvisable for me to just iterate over the rows in the csv file and do insert statements? Why should I use the CQLSSTableWriter specifically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of Cassandra do you use? The example was written with 2.1 in mind.

https://github.com/yukim/cassandra-bulkload-example/blob/master/build.gradle#L14

May want to try setting the client mode in config

```
org.apache.cassandra.config.Config.setClientMode(true);
```

Otherwise you may have issues with the databasedescriptor in the cassandra setup things that are declared statically.  You can probably work around them by putting a fake cassandra.yaml in your classpath which I think the cassandra-all package is providing for the example.

Is worth mentioning that in all likelihood, this will perform better if you just use inserts directly instead of trying to bulk load it.

Comment: Yes, I've just decided to do inserts directly. Inserting seems to work, and I don't know what difference the bulk loader would make, if I could get it to work. Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently this a known issue caused by the following:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-8808

and should be fixed in the next release.